# Unable to debug after installing Android 5.1.1 on Nexus 5

Tags: android, macos, debugging, android-studio, usb

Today I received the Android 5.1.1 update on my Nexus 5. After updating the device I'm unable to connect it to adb (in Android Studio on Mac OS X) via USB.

Developer options are enabled, tried to toggle usb debug off & on, changed usb memory emulation from storage to camera and viceversa, rebooted the device, but no way to see my Nexus 5 listed in "Choose Device" window.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Paolo

Comment: I just got 5.1.1 on my Nexus 4, and I have no problems in accessing it from **`adb`** on Linux, so whatever your issue is, it is not something that exists across the board for 5.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue related to Mac's USB port. With another Mac everything works and rebooting issued Mac and changing USB port it worked again.

Thanks